# Compare between values

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

With 5 variables consist of a value, I would need to check if any value between fa to fe has a gap of 6 in integer as in f1=1, f2=0, f3=0, f4=7, f5=10; and between f1 and f4, which has a gap of 6.

```
var f1:int
var f2:int
var f3:int
var f4:int
var f5:int
```

How do I make the actionscript easier to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could do something like

```
var f:Array = new Array(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
f.sort();
for (var x = 0; x < f.length - 1; ++x)
{
    if (f[x+1] - f[x] >= 6)
    {
        // here's your gap
        Alert.show("Gap between "+f[x].toString()+" and "+f[x+1].toString());
    } 
}
```

Note, it'll tell you whether there's a gap, and which values are at either end of the gap, but it won't specifically say which variables are involved.  And it won't necessarily find the largest gap; it'll just find one that qualifies (as i understand the problem).

Comment: It gets trickier because he seems to want to find the largest gap > 6. In his example he says 'between f1 and f4.' An array is a good approach though, but you probably shouldn't sort it, in the case of something like [0,15,5,10,20] it won't register the 0->15 gap as being >6 because it will be sorted to [0,5,10,15,20]

Comment: "between f1 and f4" would be "between 1 and 7".  Which is just what the code i posted would find.  If he wanted the largest gap, it'd be between f2 (or f3) and f5.  I've added an extra note about what it'd find, though.

Comment: interesting, however, on the "here's your gap" can it display which array?

Comment: The note at the end details what you can find with this code.  It can tell you what values are at either end of the gap (`f[x]` and `f[x+1]`), but since the array is sorted, any relationship between the values and their original positions/variables/whatever is lost.

Comment: I see, I was actually comparing the musical notes in a chord, such as the 4's quarter notes from bottom to top: F, A, C, E. Want to compare if F and A or C or E has a gap of 6 of more. I think my question is still vague to my problem. Meanwhile, I be back in one hour.